# remove some part of a link's href value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some link with `href` attribute.

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/...variable1.../">My Link</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/...variable2.../">My Link</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/...variable3.../">My Link</a>
```

I need to get the `href` value , delete `http://stackoverflow.com` and convert link to

```
<a href="/...variable1.../">My Link</a>
<a href="/...variable2.../">My Link</a>
<a href="/...variable3.../">My Link</a>
```

For example

```
$('a').each(function () {  

     var full_link = $('a').attr('href') ;
     var delete_part = 'http://stackoverflow.com' ;
     var output = full_link - delete_part ;

     $('a').attr('href',output);

});
```

So what would you suggest me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

It will remove your domain name irrespective of what it is.

It will work for all domain names no need to specify the domain name

```
$('a').each(function () {  

     var full_link = $('a').attr('href') ;
     var output =  full_link.replace(/http?:\/\/[^\/]+/i, "");
     $('a').attr('href',output);

});
```

Comment: For your case it will work but if there is `https` or `www` in `url` make changes accordingly

Answer (score 4):

Here you are:

```
$('a').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('href', $(this).prop('href')
        .replace(/^http:\/\/stackoverflow\.com/, ''));
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Your answer helps me ;)

Answer (score 3):

Please update the code to following

```
 var full_link = $('a').attr('href') ;
 var delete_part = 'http://stackoverflow.com' ;
 var output = full_link.replace(delete_part, "") ;
```

For reference - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 2):

Try this one..

```
$('a').each(function() {  
     var full_link = $('a').attr('href');
     var delete_part = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
     var output = full_link.replace(delete_part,""); 
     $('a').attr('href',output);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').each(function () {  
     var full_link = $('a').attr('href') ;
     var delete_part = 'http://stackoverflow.com' ;
     var output = full_link.replace(delete_part, "") ;
     $('a').attr('href',output);
});
```